# BigQuery - wait UDF function with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

In Bigquery does not exist a native function like DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP (or DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP) from Oracle ("Puts a procedure to sleep for a specific time"). I tried to use an UDF with JavaScript code but it does not work as I expect: it does not stop other than forced.
Can you help me understand what's going on?
Thanks!

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JS_Sleep(x FLOAT64)
 RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }
  return sleep(x);

  """;
select JS_Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: busy loops are generally to be avoided, but how about  ```const targetDate= Date.now() + milliseconds; while(Date.now()<targetDate){}``` - aaaalso `function busySleep`

Comment: Thanks, @hanshenrik! I agreed with you about busy loops (I need just loops not with "bussy" :) ). Your code variant behaves the same: it only stops forcibly.

Comment: in that case, Date.now() is probably broken... or the argument is broken. any chance you can read console.log(milliseconds)  output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() similar with Date.now() always returns same value in a single statement or in a single transaction as if time stops regardless how many it appears in a query.

In my experience, this also applies to Date.now(). In your case, JS_Sleep() runs forever cause time stops within your query.

Comment: I agree with you on BQ and how CURRENT_TIMESTAMP () works. That's why I chose Javascript in BQ - where I didn't expect the same behavior. All my tests prove you right! Thanks for the help!